# Parsing output from wget and grep using bash

Tags: bash, grep, curl, wget

I can get a url link and search for text that starts with **file:**  but I'm having issues parsing it from there.

**Example:**

```
wget -qO- http://website.com/site/ | tr \" \\n | grep -w file:\* > output.txt
```

**The wget command Gives me the output:**

```
file: 'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs',
```

**I'm trying to get the output to look like.**

```
http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs
```

My goal is to have a bash script that includes several source / list of url's that will be looped through and each processed / grep'd output url will be on it's own separate line.

**http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs**

**As requested:**

Here's an example of the output of what 
`wget -qO- http://website.com/site/` 
sends back.

```
player.setup({
  file: 'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs',
  width: "100%",
  aspectratio: "16:9",

});
```

Comment: If you want to parse html, I recommend to use something [made for parsing html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/how-to-parse-hundred-html-source-code-files-in-shell) instead of `grep`. Depending on the actual HTML files you want to parse, you may get away with `grep`, but there'll be plenty of variants your regular expression won't catch.

Comment: can you show an example of the ACTUAL output of the `wget` command **before** any processing with tr or grep?

Comment: @cas ok I updated the question to include just what the `wget -qO- http://website.com/site/` with no processing outputs.

Comment: ok, so it's not returning HTML.  looks like it's returning a function call with embedded json.   `lynx -dump` won't work for that at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
wget -qO- http://website.com/site/ | \
  sed -n -e "/^ *file: */ { s/^ *file: *'//; s/', *$//p}" > output.txt
```

Comment: I installed it unfortunately it creates a blank file...
the line `wget -qO- http://website.com/site/ | tr \" \\n | grep -w file:\* > output.txt` works it just doesn't fully parse it the way I need it.

Comment: then please add a sample of the raw output of `wget` to your question.  Without that, only rough guesses are possible.

Comment: It's highlighted in the question under `Example`? is it not showing up in the question?

Comment: also, does the `lynx` command about **without** the `grep` show a list of links?  does your `http://website.com/site/` require authentication? if so, you might need to use the `-auth=ID:PASSWD` option.   or visit the site manually with lynx using the `--cookie_file` option and then use the same cookie file with the `lynx -dump ...` later.

Comment: @RickT no, it's not highlighted under example.  the only thing that's there is the wget command.   I'm asking for a sample of the **OUTPUT** of the wget command, not the wget command itself.

Comment: It was poor wording on my part.  the output is `file: 'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs',`  I've also labelled it as such in the question.

Comment: if the output of `wget` is large, then pick a small, **relevant** section of the output to use as the sample.  5 or 10 lines will probably be enough, depending on how fugly the HTML is.

Comment: again, no.  That is not the **raw** output - that's the output after being piped through `tr` and `grep`.

Comment: Thanks that did it!!

Comment: yeah, it works at the moment.  It's fragile, though - any change in the data returned by the web site could and probably will break it.  e.g. just removing all linefeeds from the data will a) probably be valid for the official/expected client software, but b) break the above until you edit the sed script to cope with the new situation.