# how to put all directory tags into different variables

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, scripting

I have fetched all the directory tags from a file. Now, I am stuck in a situation where I want to store that whole individual directory tags in to different variables as shown below. Thanking in advance.

Below is what I have fetched:

```html
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Required:

```
# echo $var1
<Directory /> 
AllowOverride none 
Order deny, allow 
Deny from all 
</Directory>

# echo $var2
<Directory "/var/www"> 
AllowOverride None  
Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Please note: There are not just 2 directory tags, there are many directory tags without any gap in between them. Every whole individual directory must be stored in a separate variable.

Thanking in advance

Comment: Note your first Directory tag is a self closing element. Did you mean `<Directory "/">`?

Comment: Note in the required part you have a quoting problem. If bash variables then `var1='some stuff "and some quoted stuff" and more stuff'`

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/41001475/537980 or this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6389/4778

Comment: This is completely different to what you were asking for before. You now want `var1="""` with three quotes and a multi line string? What are the three quotes for? Is this not supposed to go into shell variables? Are you using python instead?

Comment: @terdon I am using bash shell only, using of perl will also help as we have perl in our system. The 3 quotes is to indicate that if it comes as it is then it would be great. Even if it comes in a single line, it will be okay.

Comment: Please show what you need. _Exactly_ what you need. If you don't want the three quotes in the output, then don't show them. We can't guess what you are after, you need to show us.

Comment: It would also be good to know _why_ you need the XML text in separate variables. If you want to loop over them to do something, there are easier ways to do that (using e.g. `xmlstarlet`). As this looks like a web server configuration, you may want to let us know what your end goal is.

Comment: @terdon The only requirement I have is that the whole individual directory tag must be stored in a variable. If I am making you confuse with option than please consider the case where the whole individual directory tag is stored as it is in a variable. That is using three quotes. Sorry for creating the ambiguity.

Comment: @Kusalananda I can't use any third party tool on my server. Also, this text comes from a config file which is not a XML file.

Comment: Do you want the expected output as a text or variables in the script?

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ The output must be stored in variables.

Comment: @TahaTikiwala then please [edit] your question and show us _exactly_ what you want the variable to contain. Show us the output you expect from `echo "$variable"`. The three quotes are just confusing since they would be a syntax error in the shell. Do you want the newline characters in the variable? All spaces?  Just show us what you expect.

Comment: @terdon Made the changes sir as you asked.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your support too sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the lines of the file and add the new lines to a string until you encounter a `</Directory>` tag.

If you only have `Directory` tags, the code would be much simpler. You'll need to declare `varX` variables as you go using `declare` if you do not know how many tags you have.

```
STR=""
i=1
DIRTAG=false
while read -r LINE; do
    if grep -q '^<Directory' <<< $LINE; then
        DIRTAG=true
    fi
    if $DIRTAG; then
        STR+="$LINE
"
    fi
    if grep -q '^</Directory>' <<< $LINE; then 
        declare var$i="\"\"\"$STR\"\"\"" #You're not clear on the quotes
        STR=""   
        i=$((i+1))
        DIRTAG=false
    fi
done < t.txt
```

Now `echo "$var1"; echo "$var2"` outputs the following (do not forget the double quotes. Otherwise newlines will be spaces in the printed output)

```
"""<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
"""
"""<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
"""
```

When you do not know the number of tags, you can use this to iterate over the created variables

```
for j in `seq 1 $((i-1))`; do
    var=var$j
    echo "${!var}"
done
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You could process the file to convert it to a list of variable definitions and then source that. For example, you could add an empty line after each closing `</Directory>` tag, and then use perl's paragraph mode to read each entry as a single line:

```
$ sed 's|</Directory>|</Directory>\n|' file | 
    perl -000 -lne 'print "var" . ++$k . "=\"$_\"";' 
var1="<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>"

var2="<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>"
```

And you could source that directly to actually set the variables in your current shell:

```
$ . <(sed 's|</Directory>|</Directory>\n|' file | 
    perl -000 -lne 'print "var" . ++$k . "=\"$_\"";' file )

$ echo "$var1"
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

$ echo "$var2"
<Directory /var/www>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

#### Explanation

- `sed s|</Directory>|</Directory>\n|' file`: add a newline after each closing `</Directory>` tag.
- `-000` : this turns on perl's "paragraph mode" where a "line" is defined by two consecutive newline characters, basically a blank line. So instead of real lines, each "line" is now a paragraph. This lets us treat everything between the opening and closing `< Directory />` as a single line since each entry is separated by a blank line.
- `-lne`: The `-l` removes trailing newlines and adds a `\n` to each `print`. The `-n` reads the input file line by line (see above for what "line" means in this context) and applies the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `print "var" . ++$k . "=\"$_\""`: print the desired output format: the string `var` followed by a number which is incremented for each processed line (`++$k`), then `=\"` (the `"` needs to be escaped as `\"` since we are within a double-quoted string) and the current "line" (`$_` ) followed by the closing `"`.
- `. <(perl ...)`: the `.` is the source command, it will read the fle you give it and run its contents in the current session. The `<()` is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), essentially it allows us to treat the output of a command as though it were a file. Note that not all shells support this, so if yours doesn't, you might have to save the output into a file and then source that file.

Comment: I'd suggest that if using perl, use the [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General) module to parse an apache config file

Comment: @glennjackman would that help getting the values into shell variables as requested by the OP? I've never used it, myself.

Comment: I'd post an example, but Config::General is not happy with the extra whitespace inside the angle brackets

Comment: @terdon 
thanks for the help, but what if there is no gap between two directory tags. I am currently having 5 directory tags one after the another without any blank line separating them.

Comment: @TahaTikiwala then you should have shown that in your question. I can't guess what your file looks like. Please edit your question and give an example that accurately represents your file so we don't waste your time, or ours, giving solutions that don't help.

Comment: @terdon I apologize for the same. My bad. I have now made the changes accordingly. Thanking you in advance